# JavaScript Code Inside <script> Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, firebug-lite

Apparently a JSON object can be passed inside a linked script. I'm trying to figure out exactly how this works (or if it does):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js">
{
    overrideConsole: false,
    startInNewWindow: true,
    startOpened: true,
    enableTrace: true
}
</script>
```

I noticed it here in the firebug lite documentation:
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#ScriptJSONOptions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The content is not executed because the element has a `src` attribute.  It's not strictly legal as is.  The [HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) says:

> If there is a `src` attribute, the element must be either empty or contain only script documentation that also matches script content restrictions.

The content of that `<script>` element is neither valid JSON nor valid JavaScript.  It is not valid JSON because the property names are not quoted.  It is not valid JavaScript because, although it looks like a block expression with labeled statements, the colon after `startInNewWindow` cannot legally appear there.

That said, the script that is loaded can always look for the last script element and parse its content:

```
 var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');
 var lastScript = scripts[script.length - 1];
 var content = eval(lastScript.innerText || lastScript.textContent);
```

Answer (score 6):

The browser will ignore any content in `<script src />` tag.

However, the Firebug Lite Javascript will specifically find its `<script>` tag and parse the content manually.

Comment: Cool thanks. I think i found it! http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/lite/branches/firebug1.5/build/firebug-lite-debug.js#478

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in question that parses the JSON object in case anyone is interested.

```
// process the Script JSON Options
var innerOptions = FBL.trim(script.innerHTML);
if (innerOptions) {
    var innerOptionsObject = eval("(" + innerOptions + ")");

    for (var name in innerOptionsObject) {
        var value = innerOptionsObject[name];

        if (name == "debug") {
            Env.isDebugMode = !!value;
        }
        else if (name in Env.Options) {
            Env.Options[name] = value;
        }
        else {
            Env[name] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/lite/branches/firebug1.5/build/firebug-lite-debug.js#478